# Название или реализация техники из описания

Tags: javascript

Интересует, есть ли какое то название для следующей техники, и существует ли реализация в какой либо библиотеке?

Суть такова:
есть некая функция, которая возвращает данные по нескольким id, например

```
const getInfo = async (ids) => {...}
```

есть функция которая  которая получает данные по одному id, например const

```
const getInfoById = async (id) => {...}
```

Я ожидаю такое поведение от данной функции, например мы делаем несколько вызовов данной функции

```
await getInfoById(1)
await getInfoById(2)
await getInfoById(3)
await getInfoById(4)
await getInfoById(5)
```

она должна накапливать в очереди id, и только на следующем цикле event loop она единственным вызовом `getInfo` получает данные по всем id из очереди, и возвращает соответствующие значения. Можно не на следующем цикле event loop, а например через определенное время с первого вызова в очереди. В идеале хотелось бы иметь функцию обертку типа debounce из lodash

Comment: Смотри Promise.All

Comment: А в твоём случае если всё последовательно происходит, то после цикла, где запрашиваются объекты по одному,  достаточно и написать метод getInfo

Comment: А ещё проще, сразу вызвать getInfo....зачем нужны вообще getInfoById  если в итоге нужен getInfo?

Comment: Можно getInfo положить в setInterval, а getInfoById сохраняют результат в массив. getInfo будет брать все значения из массива, опрашивать и удалять обработанное.

Comment: То, о чем вы говорите, напоминает технику, часто называемую "batching" или "debouncing запросов" в контексте асинхронных вызовов.

Comment: getInfo может быть медленной функцией, например запрашивать данные по сети, поэтому каждый раз запрашивать можно, но это будет плохо. Таже вызовы getInfoById  могут быть разбросаны по коду, как то объединить их нельзя, или трудозатратно.

Comment: *"getInfo может быть медленной функцией ...... каждый раз запрашивать плохо"* ---  решается кэшированием моментально.................... "*вызовы getInfoById могут быть разбросаны по коду*" --- это очень странно, но предположим. Тогда складировать данные в единое хранилище надо. Тут даже обёртки особо не нужно велосипедить. Дописать пару строк в getInfoById

Comment: А если есть время что-то поменять, то применить шаблон "Flyweight" для данных дел... Он немного о другом, но будет примерно подходить

Comment: кешерование не совсем то.  getInfo оправдано вызывать только для многих аргументов, а для одного не оправдано. Пусть даже мы закешируем, мы все равно отправим 20 запросов по одному айди вместо одного с 20 айди. Но в коде удобно использовать функцию для одного аргумента.

Comment: в качестве очереди создайте массив и пуште в него ид"ы, а когда "пришло время" `you_array.forEach('getInfoById')`. я бы так сделал. `мы все равно отправим 20 запросов по одному айди вместо одного с 20 айди` ну... это смотря у кого и как запрашивать. если у SQL бд, там и всю таблицу можно взять одним запросом. но да, к кешированию это отношение не сильно то и имеет. `есть ли какое то название для следующей техники?` напомнило "брокеры сообщений" и всё с ними связанное.